# jquery tooltip with delay on show

Tags: jquery, tooltip

i wrote a very simple tooltip script with pre delay on show.

but i have some problem with my code

i dont want too show the tooltip that has less than 500 ms hover time but i have blink effect because of fadeTo() animation effect

this means when i hover on .imgSpan and then quickly unhover the mouse less than 500 ms, the .img tag will show after 500 ms and quickly hide

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.img').css('display','none');
});
$('.imgSpan').hover(
function(){
    $(".imgSpan:hover .img").delay(500).fadeTo(500, 1);
},
function(){
    $(".img").css("display", "none");
    $(".img").fadeTo(0, 0);
}
);
```

HTML Code:

```
<span class='imgSpan'>
<a>
<img src='/images/image.png' class='middle' />
</a>
<img class='img' src='image_path' alt='image' />
```

notes:

- i dont want to lose animation effect
- i dont want to use any plugin

Comment: jQuery does'nt target pseudo selectors like :hover !

Comment: could you add the HTML you're using too?

Comment: question edited and HTML code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of a wrong queuing.

To correct that, you can write the CSS line like that:

```
$(".img").stop(true, true).css("display", "none");
```

This will clear every animation on the selector and then change the CSS.

Im not sure but I think you can remove the second `true` on stop. You just have to try it!

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.imgSpan:hover` is incorrect.

Since you've not mentioned HTML, assuming ( by selector mentioned in question which is  `$(".imgSpan:hover .img")` ie child of `.imgSpan`),

```
<div class="imgSpan">Hover me
<div class="img">Some</div>
</div>
```

Here's correct js -

```
$('.img').css('display','none');
$('.imgSpan').hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".img").delay(1000).fadeTo(500, 1);
},function(){
    $(".img").css("display", "none");
    $(".img").fadeTo(0, 0);
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/A4raC/1/)